# Instrumenting Angular project for coverage for protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor, code-coverage, istanbul

In Windows, I'm trying to do code coverage for my Angular project when running Protractor tests. I'm trying to instrument my code and followed these steps:

I set the NODE_OPTIONS env variable as follows in windows:

1. I created an environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS` and set the value to `--max_old_space_size=14336` (using System Environment Variables dialog in windows)
2. In addition to that, in command prompt, I ran the following command: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=14336`
   (I assume that the memory used is going to be 14GB)

Added the following `.nycrc` file to the project root folder:

```
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "all": true,
    "report-dir": ".cypress-coverage",
    "extension": [
      ".js",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "json",
      "html"
    ],
    "parserPlugins": [
      "decorators-legacy",
      "decorators",
      "typescript"
    ]
}
```

Then from the project root folder, I ran the command for instrumenting using istandul:

```
nyc instrument ./dist ./coverage/instrumented
```

(please note: `dist` folder contains the angular project build output (distribution))

after a few minutes the command was run, this error was reported:

```
D:\myproj>nyc instrument ./dist ./coverage/instrumented
<--- Last few GCs --->

[11804:0000022A18C7C510]  1864090 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 14315.9 (14349.6) -> 14315.3 (14349.9) MB, 51.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.346, current mu = 0.310) allocation failure
[11804:0000022A18C7C510]  1864137 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 14316.1 (14346.9) -> 14315.5 (14347.9) MB, 22.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.346, current mu = 0.310) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF75D643E0F napi_wrap+108911
 2: 00007FF75D5E7E16 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+61910
 3: 00007FF75D5E8D16 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF75DEC0CEE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF75DEA5ACD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF75DD4F95C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF75DD5ACEA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF75DD57E99 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF75DD4CA71 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
10: 00007FF75DD4AC95 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF75DD6AFEB v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+203
12: 00007FF75DA99E0F v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1039
13: 00007FF75DF49BAD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+465229
14: 000000E91F5021E8
```

For some reasons, I'm unable to share the project that I'm working on. For your information:

1. Total size of all source files: 8MB
2. Size of all .js files in the build output `dist` folder: approx. 100MB

Answer (score 0):

I increased heap size to 24GB and it seems to work fine !

set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=24576
Also, set NODE_OPTIONS in System env variables dialog.

Can anyone review this and confirm if it is the right solution?